# How can I use a data attribute to set a background-image in CSS?

Tags: css, custom-data-attribute

I have a folder with a few background images (one.jpg, two.jpg, three.jpg) , and this markup

```
<section class="slide" data-bg="one"></section>
<section class="slide" data-bg="two"></section>
<section class="slide" data-bg="three"></section>
```

Would it be possible somehow **just with CSS** to do something like this?

```
.slide{
    background-image: url(img/attr(data-bg).jpg);
}
```

This code isnt working, of course.

Comment: not with pure css, but with javascript - is this an option for you?

Comment: My goal was to get it with CSS

Comment: You're *supposed* to be able to do this with [the CSS3-enhanced version of `attr()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#attr) (except you need to quote the strings), but there are no known implementations. Your only way is to hardcode them as oezi suggests.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This won't be possible with pure css unless you're doing it the "undynamic" way:

```css
.slide[data-bg="one"]{
  background-image: url('img/one.jpg');
}
.slide[data-bg="two"]{
  background-image: url('img/two.jpg');
}
...
```

Maybe you can dynamically create that stylesheet from your filenames on server-side.

Another (likely easier) possibility is to do this with JavaScript - but since you excluded that I assume you know about that and just don't want to use it.

Comment: Sucks :( Thanks. I could use SASS, but not my preferred solution.

Answer (score 1):

I know the original question stressed doing it with just CSS, but I got to this question because another question (that wasn't necessarily asking for a CSS solution) was marked as a duplicate of this. Here's what I'm using as the solution, in case it helps anyone else, and it uses javascript w/jQuery:

```
$('.slide').each(function (index) {
    var slide = $(this);
    slide.css('background-image', 'url(' + slide.data('bg') + ')');
});
```