# Using HTML attributes as CSS property values

Tags: css

The spec says:

> The attr() function returns the **value of an attribute on the element for use as a value in a property**. If used on a pseudo-element, it returns the value of the attribute on the pseudo-element's originating element.

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#attr

However, this doesn't seem to work. When I use `background-image: url(attr(href));` I get string "attr(href)" as attribute value, not the value itself.

http://jsfiddle.net/x2Rpt/1/

Any ideas why this is broken?

Comment: Almost the same as this question asked earlier today: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11117915/how-can-i-use-a-data-attribute-to-set-a-background-image-in-css

Comment: @thirtydot: I knew this seemed familiar... dunno if I should close it or leave my answer.

Comment: So basically, it should work, but it isn't implemented quite right?

Comment: The CSS3 version isn't implemented at all. The only available implementations are based on the CSS2.1 definition - http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html

Comment: @thirtydot: Well, here's the earliest question about CSS3's `attr()` that I can find: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8769786/css3s-attr-doesnt-work-in-major-browsers It's not easy to search without having to wade through thousands of jQuery questions...

Comment: @BoltClock: So I should link to that one in the future as it's the closest thing to a canonical answer?

Comment: @thirtydot: I suppose so. VTC the rest if you'd like and I'll clean up the comments.

Answer (score 15):

It's not broken; it's just that no browser has implemented [the CSS3 version of `attr()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#attr). Currently, implementations only exist for the one that was [introduced in CSS2.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#x18), which is limited to the `content` property for generated and replaced content.

Your syntax seems correct otherwise, until and unless changes are made to the spec.

Comment: please up-vote this bug to get them work on implementation: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=435426